# Controlling video buffering via Youtube API

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using Android Youtube API and I was wondering if there is a way to control video buffering. I'm specifically interested in the possibility of pausing the buffering and resuming it later on with the idea to download video gradually by chunks.

Any kind of help or workarounds highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the following methods available with a [`YouTubePlayer`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer).

[`pause()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#pause%28%29)

[`play()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#play%28%29)

[`seekToMillis (int milliSeconds)`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#seekToMillis%28int%29)

[`seekRelativeMillis (int milliSeconds)`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#seekRelativeMillis%28int%29)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I'm looking for - I know how to play the video, I'm interested in controlling the way the video is buffering. Specifically I would like to stop downloading the video when the signal is too low while continuing playing it until it reaches the point which is no longer buffered.

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube API has a method [stopVideo()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#stopVideo) that you may be able to use. Unlike the `pause()` method, it will stop downloading the video. I'm not sure if you can resume the video afterwards, but at least it stops buffering.

Comment: That is true, but it's not really applicable to the use case I described. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

For all it's worth, I didn't find a way to achieve this using YouTube API and I don't think there is one (correct me if I'm wrong).

I ended up abandoning YouTube API completely and solving the problem in an adhoc way - the app determines the actual location of the video file and downloads it progressively to a temporary file using standard means, which gives it full control over the connection. The data is read and fed to the media player simultaneously as it's being downloaded, performing second-level local buffering.